# Test files for plugin development

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

The end of the first chapter of Professional WordPress Plugin Development
by Wrox Press released February 2011 states:

> To test a plugin during development make a `test.php` file and place it
>   in the WordPress installation root directory.

However I've run a search in Aptana Studio for `test.php` in the WordPress
source code and cannot find it. Where is the code which supposedly loads
this file from WordPress's root directory and does it have to be named
`test.php` or can it be also named something else?

Comment: Is this a physical book or can you link to it? I never heard of such a file before. Maybe there's context to that? If so: Please explain in an [edit].

Comment: It's a physical book. I've updated my post accordingly. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: As you are saying, it states that test.php has to be created but what is the purpose of it? Why that is required when you can directly test your plugin from its main file.

Comment: Instead of doing this, perhaps PHPUnit or behat would be a better more structured way to test your code

Answer (score 1):

WordPress does not look for test.php; instead, you load it in your browser, like http://example.com/test.php.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What I wanted to know is, where is the WordPress source code which will actually load this test.php file. I have searched the source code for test.php and found nothing.

Comment: I clarified my answer.

Comment: Still not sure what the advantage is of testing a plugin in this way and what would go inside such a file to test the plugin using the method described in the book.

Comment: Not for testing the complete plugin, but in the manner that @tom-j-nowell [mentioned](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/161561/test-files-for-plugin-development/161638?noredirect=1#comment234281_161561), as a unit test. For example, I test my plugin's update procedure this way first.